# How to click a button located within a span within another span?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver, selenium-chromedriver, browser-automation

I have tried to find the elements using *xpath*, *cssSelector* and *id*. Nothing seems to work.

```
<span class="a-button a-spacing-top-mini s-small-margin-left" id="a-autoid-60">
    <span class="a-button-inner">
        <input class="a-button-input" type="submit" value="Go" aria-labelledby="a-autoid-60-announce">
        <span class="a-button-text" aria-hidden="true" id="a-autoid-60-announce">Go</span>
    </span>
</span>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you tried to locate it with **value** ? If no, then you can use:

```
driver.findElement(By.value("GO")).click;
```

You can use **cssSelector** as :

```
driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("span[class$='button-inner']>input"))
```

You can use **Xpath** as :

```
//input[contains(@class,'button-input')][@value='Go']
```

**Note** :

1. You should always pick **ID** first , then **className** , **value** , **tagName** , **linkText** , **partialLinkText** , then **cssSelector** and if nothing works out then **Xpath**
2. The problem with ID in your case is , it contains **numeric**, we don't know when it's gonna be change , hence ID is **inconsistent** in your case.

Hope this will help you !
Let me know if you have any concerns related to this.

Comment: Thanks for your help, this works perfectly and explains why it failed with my approach.

Answer (score 0):

Add an id to the input submit button. In other words:

```
    <input id="mySubmitButton" class="a-button-input" type="submit" ....
```

Then you should be able to do:

```
    driver.findElement(By.id("mySubmitButton")).click();
```

However, if you really don't want to add an id for some reason, just search by the cssSelector:

```
    driver.findElement(By.cssSelector("#a-autoid-60 .a-button-inner input")).click();
```

Comment: Adding the id works. I was trying to get it to work as is but it does not find the element using the cssSelector you mentioned.